# Convert VSTO add-in to web add-in

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

I have developed a VSTO add in for Excel, but i want to have it available for MACs, is there any way to convert the VSTO addin to Web addin? I have looked at the documentation that microsoft have posted about sharing code, but then it seems that you need to have developed both add ins, and then share the code.